# Getting a fatal error while updating

Tags: php, functions, updates

Every time i tried to update WordPress ,i faced this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in
>   G:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\Requests\Transport\fsockopen.php on
>   line 246

Code of line number 246 is:

```
$block = fread($socket, Requests::BUFFER_SIZE);
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This issue generally occurs when php script takes more time for execution than set in php.ini file

You can resolve this issue by using two methods:

Method 1: Editing .htaccess File Manually

Put **php_value max_execution_time 600** in .htaccess file 600 is the value of execution time in seconds, you can use yours value, the maximum value is better.

Method 2: You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maximum-execution-time-exceeded/ plugin to maximise the execution tome

Comment: tnks,for your valuable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the maximum execution time of PHP.

You can do that on `php.ini`, on `.htaccess` or probably you can do it in the `wp-config.php` file.

For mores information, visit [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Maximum_execution_time_exceeded) codex page.

Comment: tnks, it have solved my wordpress update problem.